# Qt QListWidget Item with Alternating Colors

Tags: qt, design-patterns, qlistwidget

I'm trying to get like a checkerboard pattern into a `QListWidget`. for example, have the first item in the list a dark grey background, and the second item in the list would have a light grey background and keep alternating like that as it goes down. Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

I know I can do it by creating a class, extending a `QListWidget` and then just set the styles in it each time the list updates but I'm looking for the simplest way possible. Any answers would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 listWidget->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
```

It's a built-in property of Qt.

If you use designer:

[image]

Comment: That did it. Then I just had to set the ":alternate" pseudo state in the css. Thanks allot!

Comment: Nope. You should also take a look at DNamto's answer. Using `setStytleSheet` to adjust the type of alternating colors is much more simpler.

Comment: I always use stylesheets if I can. I prefer the ":alternate" pseudo state. I think it keeps things more organized.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this should work

```
myList->setAlternatingRowColors(true);
myList->setStyleSheet("alternate-background-color: white;background-color: black;");
```

Answer (score 0):

**use pseudo-state - :alternate in stylesheet**

**Example:**

```cpp
QListView::item {
    background-color: #1C80A6;
    color: white;}
QListView::item:alternate {
    background-color: white;
    color: #1C80A6;}
```